# Как производить поиск в БД MySQL по 2 параметрам Python

Tags: python, mysql

Нужно проводить поиск по 2 параметрам в бд `MySQL` используя `Python`, как это можно осуществлять?

```
mycursor.execute(f"SELECT id, mention FROM discord_user where id={str(user.id)},mention={str(user.mention)}")
mycursor.execute(f"SELECT id, mention FROM discord_user where id={str(user.id)} AND mention={str(user.mention)}")
```

Примеры сверху выдают одну и ту же ошибку:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
>   exception: ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near '=<@!401653705927294976>' at
>   line 1

Comment: А так `mycursor.execute("SELECT id, mention FROM discord_user where id=? AND mention=?", (user.id, user.mention))`?

Comment: Предложенный выше вариант вызывает другу ошибку
```mycursor.execute("SELECT id, mention FROM discord_user where id=? AND mention=?", (user.id, user.mention))
```
Ошибка:
```discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Comment: Похоже, символы-заменители для клиента `mysql` отличаются от `sqlite3`, сделайте так: `mycursor.execute("SELECT id, mention FROM discord_user where id=%s AND mention=%s", (user.id, user.mention))`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Мне казалось что я пробывал данный метод, но нет.
- Оно работает!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте составить запрос, используя биндинг:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT id, mention FROM discord_user where id=%s AND mention=%s", (user.id, user.mention))
```